# Accessing current data iteration from parent component

Tags: javascript, html, alpine.js

I want to access current data iteration from template, and also I need certain id's from iterated element.

```html
<template x-for="(datas, idx) in data">
                <tr x-bind:class="idx % 2 == 0 ? 'bg-white' : 'bg-green-100'" class="border-4 border-gray-200">
                    <td class="text-center py-2 w-2">
                        <span x-text="`${parseInt(idx) + 1}`"></span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-center py-2">
                        <strong x-text="datas.name"></strong>
                        <br />
                        <i x-text="`Num : ${datas.num}`"></i>
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-center py-2" >
                        <!--I need access datas.num in this area v--->
                        <div @click.away="open = false" class="relative" x-data="{open : false}">
                            <button @click="open = !open" class="bg-gray-300 flex flex-row items-center w-full px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold text-left bg-transparent rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-transparent dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 md:w-auto md:inline md:mt-0 md:ml-4 hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline">
                                <span>Action</span>
                                <svg fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 20 20" :class="{'rotate-180': open, 'rotate-0': !open}" class="inline w-4 h-4 mt-1 ml-1 transition-transform duration-200 transform md:-mt-1"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5.293 7.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 10.586l3.293-3.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd"></path></svg>
                            </button>
                            <div x-show="open" x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-100" x-transition:enter-start="transform opacity-0 scale-95" x-transition:enter-end="transform opacity-100 scale-100" x-transition:leave="transition ease-in duration-75" x-transition:leave-start="transform opacity-100 scale-100" x-transition:leave-end="transform opacity-0 scale-95" class="absolute right-0 w-full mt-2 origin-top-right rounded-md shadow-lg md:w-48" style="z-index: 1;">
                                <div class="px-2 py-2 bg-white rounded-md shadow dark-mode:bg-gray-800">
                                    <a class="block px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold bg-transparent rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-transparent dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 md:mt-0 hover:text-gray-900 focus:text-gray-900 hover:bg-gray-200 focus:bg-gray-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" href="#"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i> Edit</a>
                                    <a @click="$parent.deleteData(datas.num)" class="block px-4 py-2 mt-2 text-sm font-semibold bg-transparent rounded-lg dark-mode:bg-transparent dark-mode:hover:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:bg-gray-600 dark-mode:focus:text-white dark-mode:hover:text-white dark-mode:text-gray-200 md:mt-0 hover:text-white-900 focus:text-white-900 hover:bg-red-200 focus:bg-red-200 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> Delete</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </template>
```

and here's `data` definition :

```js
   function dataInit(){
     return {
       data : [
       {
         num : 10,
         name : "josh"
       }
       ],
       deleteData(id){
          //do something with current id selection
       }
    }
   }
```

I do can access method of `deleteData(id)` in parent because using Alpine's magic helper, but I can't access `datas.num` or `$parent.deleteData(datas.num)` variable in loop block even they're inside template block. How do I resolve this problem?

Edit :
*Assuming the x-data for data loop is already set in upper element
** What I meant is that, I want to access the `x-for` in child element ( see comments on html's section). But I can't access it, maybe some scope problems that prevent me to do it. Starting in this area `<div @click.away="open = false" class="relative" x-data="{open : false}">`

Answer (score 0):

Your `deleteData` function is within an object, so referring to other elements within that object requires [`this`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_this.asp) to refer to itself:

```js
deleteData(id) {
    let data = this.data;
}
```

will return the data variable.

Another thing, you've defined data as an array of objects. So, to access the num variable, you'd have to first access that specific object within the array, and then you can get the `num` value:

`this.data[0].num` should do the trick.

P.S. your code snippet is missing one closing bracket (`}`)

Within Alpine, you *don't* need to refer to the object, since you should be setting it as `x-data` somewhere, from which you can then do whatever you wish with the data.

```html
<div x-data="dataInit()">
    <!-- Loop the array of data -->
    <template x-for="singleData in data">
        <div>
            <span x-text="singleData.num"></span>
        </div>
    </template>
</div>
```